# Is platform_device_register() necessary?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, platform

I've read a number of articles about using platfrom device system in Linux. For example, [kernel.org document](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/driver-model/platform.txt) and [platform device/driver vs i2c device/driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27743652/platform-device-driver-vs-i2c-device-driver).
As I understand, for using platform device in Linux I need to go through 2 steps:

1. register the platform driver by `platform_driver_register()` function;
2. register the device by `platform_device_register()` or `platform_add_devices()` function.

Also it says, it is important to define the same names fields in `platform_driver` and `platform_device` structures to bind device to driver (or platform driver to device driver ?).

I looked at platform driver for Synopsys DesignWare I2C device at *drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-designware-platdrv.c*.
It seems to be platform driver and there is `platform_driver_register()` function call in __init section and driver name is set to `i2c_designware`. I supposed the appropriate device driver should exist somewhere in kernel source code. So I tried to find it by:

`grep -rne "i2c_designware"`

There are several file with matching, but nowhwre is there a call of `platform_device_register()` or `platform_add_devices()`. So, I see platform driver registration, but don't see platform device registration...

Could somebody explain this?

Comment: No, it com[lete depends on how the actual device is going to be instantiated. Most of them does **not** requre either _step 1_ and/or _step 2_. Yes, I can explain this: it's different type (rather usual) of instantiation of the devices, i.e. via ACPI or Device Tree. It calls the `platform_add_device()` but in places you probably never thought about. For example, for ACPI case: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/acpi/acpi_platform.c#L154.

Comment: On top of that, don't forget about multi-functional devices, e.g. for Intel Skylake and newer SoCs it's being handled in the _drivers/mfd/intel-lpss.c_ via MFD core that creates a platform device.

Comment: Thanks, Oandry! Now it became clearer. So, for example, it is enough to "register" device in Device Tree system to provide device registration instead of calling `platform_add_device()`  directly, isn`t it?

Comment: Yes, for Device Tree enabled platforms. Read this: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/of/platform.c#L335 for the details.