# Platform device framework and I2C device framework

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Can Someone tell me, in linux driver, When Platform device framework and I2C device framework should be used?

I have an audio codec which has I2C and I2S interface. I thought of connecting it in I2C device framework. But in the the reference driver, they have used Platform device framework.

Can someone explain the concept behind this?

Comment: Read the data sheet to understand what I2C interface of your chipset is capable of. Is it for control function or data transmission related function. As per my understanding, audio codecs have I2C interface for control functions.

Comment: Yes I2C interface is used for Control and I2S is for data transmission. I have connected it over I2C framework (using i2c_add_driver). I am able to make it working. I just want to know if same can be implemented over Platform bus framework also (platform_driver_register)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Platform driver and normal device driver..?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610570/what-is-the-difference-between-platform-driver-and-normal-device-driver)

Comment: You have to use I2C framework, but better to look at `sound/soc` folder first for examples.