# Device Drivers for System on Chip (SOC)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, soc

I want to read the GPS data from my android phone inside the kernel space. I want to write a device driver for my GPS and request data through it. But unlike external devices I could not find the Vendor Id and device Id of the GPS hardware or the SOC on which it is installed. Can someone help me with how to collect the details required for writing the driver?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the GPS unit currently not utilized? Otherwise your premise is flawed. What makes you think that there isn't a device driver for the GPS unit already in the kernel?  How would the phone/system obtain any GPS data if there was no device driver to access the GPS unit?

Answer (score 1):

You already have found one of many problems with SOC and device drivers. Therefore another approach is used in the linux kernel: Platform driver and Platform devices. You wont need any Vendor IDs and such stuff. 
I recommend you to read some tutorials and get started with it:
Readme: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/driver-model/platform.txt
Code example for CAN: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/net/can/ifi_canfd
Disscussion about difference: [What is the difference between a Linux platform driver and normal device driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610570/what-is-the-difference-between-a-linux-platform-driver-and-normal-device-driver)

Sadly I am not able to answer your questions on how to get those id's.