# Power management functions in Linux platform drivers

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am going through the platform drivers for power management operations.
The platform drivers are represented using *[struct platform_driver](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/platform_device.h#L204)*.

This structure has functions like suspend() and resume() and the power management functions are present under

*struct platform_driver->struct device_driver->const struct dev_pm_ops*

I have the following queries related to this:

1. How are the *suspend()/resume()* present in *[struct platform_driver](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/platform_device.h#L204)* different from *suspend()/resume()* functions present in *[const struct dev_pm_ops](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/pm.h#L278)*.
2. How are the power management functions present in *[const struct dev_pm_ops](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/pm.h#L278)* gets called.

Is there any good tutorial available for understanding the platform drivers.

Comment: I think the first question has answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610570/what-is-the-difference-between-a-linux-platform-driver-and-normal-device-driver). To the second question, these prototypes are probably the same as `file_operations` that you're probably already familiar with. Each device can register his own function that will be triggered once one of those prototypes is issued. See [runtime_pm.rst](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/runtime_pm.rst) for more info.

Comment: 1) the first is the definition of the **legacy** PM methods; 2) read _drivers/base/power/_ source code, it has all answers you need. There is also documentation in the kernel source tree. Have you read it? What is your particular question?