# How do I know what type of a driver I need to write?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

In the Linux source code, various types of drivers are defined, along with their related registration function and so on so forth. For example we have platform drivers and device drivers, etc. To register them we have `platform_driver_register` or `alloc_chrdev_region` (along with cdev_init, etc.). Some of those functions also need to be accompanied by the definition of a device class. There are also different types of hardware, for example on-chip hardware devices, plug-in devices like USB or even hardware modules programmed in MPSoCs accessible via I/O mappings.

My question is: how do I choose which type of driver is suitable for each kind of hardware and which functions are to be used with it?

Comment: You get a book on writing Linux device drivers such as one by Jonathan Corbet et al, and read it.

Comment: I am not asking how to write a driver, I have read various books on the subject, even more recent ones that Corbet and I have also written a couple simple drivers for DMA. My problem is that most books present one or another way of doing the things I asked but don't mention other ways (most of the time) to do it. 

For example, on one of the drivers I used `platform_driver_register` for the driver and `misc_register` for the device and it worked. I could have used `cdev_init` and it still would have worked. But I don't really understand which is the correct choice between them and why.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610570/what-is-the-difference-between-a-linux-platform-driver-and-normal-device-driver

Comment: Before you can determine "*what type of a driver I need to write*", you need to establish why you need/want to write a driver. IOW what (hardware) device do you have that needs a driver? The device itself and how it fits into the Linux kernel framework typically establishes the type of driver required.

Comment: The cited link (from `n.m.`) and its links specify the issue. AFAICT, a platform driver is a "virtual" driver that allows you to attach a device specific driver on platforms that do _not_ have H/W autodiscovery of devices. That is, on x86, we have PCIe and PnP (plug-and-play) where the kernel can probe for the H/W devices on boot. A number of arches (e.g. embedded systems or arm CPUs such as Raspberry Pi) do _not_ have this. So, the exact H/W config must be delineated in a file. This file is often a DTB (device tree blob) that describes the H/W in an OS agnostic way.